# Was this figure of speech translated correctly?

Tags: traduction

In J.D.Salinger's "The Catcher in the Rye", the protagonist recalls a book he read:

> It was a lousy book, but this Blanchard guy was pretty good. He had this big chateau and all in the Riviera, in Europe, and all he did in his spare time was beat women off with a club. He was a real rake and all, but he knocked women out.

Now, "beat women off with a club", in the original, is a non-literal figure of speech. It refers to rejecting romantic advances (more often used in the form "beat men/women off with a stick", but using a club instead makes no difference here).

There are two translations of the book in French. The one by Jean-Baptiste Rossi goes

> C'était un sale bouquin, mais ce gars Blanchard s'y connaissait. Il avait ce grand château et tout sur la Riviera, en Europe, et tout ce qu'il faisait de son temps, c'était de battre les femmes à coups de canne. C'était un vrai sadique et tout, mais il plaisait vachement aux femmes.

The one by Anne Saumont goes

> Un livre pourri mais ce Blanchard était pas mal. Il avait un grand château et tout en Europe, sur la Riviera, et là il passait son temps à battre des femmes à coups de club de golf. C’était un vrai tombeur et tout; les femmes lui résistaient pas.

My question is: can the French phrases ("battre les femmes à coups de canne", "battre des femmes à coups de club de golf") carry the same metaphorical meaning (rejecting their romantic advances), or do they have to be understood as literally beating women, and then, I guess, be classed as translation mistakes?

Comment: I've never seen these in French, so I think it is safe to assume they are translation mistakes. And for what it's worth, Google does not find anything relevant for these sentences.

Comment: The proper translation would be in-between, none of them is on point.

Comment: "Repousser les femmes à coup de canne" starts to make sense, but it's still an unusual expression.

Comment: I gather “repousser à coup de canne” would be a sensible improvement.

Comment: @Carnelune: Ha, you beat me to it :p

Comment: Hmm... I'd say the use of "club" does slightly change the tone to a more brutal one, not only rejecting the swarms of women who make advances on him but, since any change to a formula is salient, going a bit further in the injury implied in that operation. There is also of course the irony of saying he (intentionally) spent his time doing this rather than the usual obligation: "He *had to* beat them off with a stick." As the author goes on to imply, he seeks out the women he rejects. In any case, yup, these translators have missed the point. (At least Rossi gets the meaning of "knock out"!)

Comment: @Luke: Fair point. Maybe “rejeter à coup de canne” then. At least, it sounds like it could be considered an activity.

Comment: Alternatively, it's possible to keep the play on the literal/non-literal meaning of words: “[…] et tout ce qu'il faisait de son temps, c'était de repousser les femmes à coups de massue. C'était un vrai sadique et tout, mais il les faisait toutes tomber”.

Comment: @Stéphane Seems good enough for an answer!

Answer (score 1):

Les deux traductions sont des contresens. « Battre des femmes à coup de … », ça veut dire vraiment dire les frapper avec cet instrument.

J'ai l'impression que les deux traducteurs on eu de gros problèmes avec l'anglais sur ce coup.

- Je ne connais pas le contexte, mais « *lousy book* », a priori, c'est un livre qui est mauvais au sens ennuyeux, pas mauvais au sens moral du terme. Donc « sale bouquin » ne convient pas, et « pourri » n'est pas terrible.
- La « Riviera », ça existe en français, mais si le château de Blanchard est en France, on dirait qu'il est sur la « Côte d'Azur ».
- « *beat women off with a club* », comme tu le fais remarquer, ça veut dire qu'il repousse les assauts de femmes éprises, pas qu'il les frappe.
- Le mot « *rake* » ne désigne pas du tout un « sadique » et pas tout à fait un « tombeur » (sinon il n'y aurait pas l'opposition avec « *but …* »). C'est plutôt un dilettante, souvent libertin, qui cherche la promiscuité mais ne la trouve pas forcément facilement.

Traduction personnelle :

> Le bouquin était chiant, mais ce type, Blanchard, c'était quelque chose. Il avait ce château super sur la Côte d'Azur, et il tournait toutes les têtes autour de lui. C'était un complet dilettante et pourtant tombait les femmes à qui mieux-mieux.

Comment: Tu comprends « sale » comme mauvais au sens moral ? Pas moi, pas dans ce contexte, au contraire je trouve que la traduction est bien trouvée. « Dilettante » par contre ça me plait, rien d'autre ne me satisfaisait.